# Icon bar burger not working and displaying only one horizontal line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to create a responsive layout button that looks like this:

[image]

But the problem is that I'm not being able to create the three horizontal lines, only one of them. Staying this way:

[image]

My code:

**HTML**

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.navbar-toggler span {
  height: 4px;
  background: #545454;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.navbar-toggler span:before, .navbar-toggler span:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: do you want it as only by button?

Comment: It could be by other ways, but it has to show the three horizontal lines.

Comment: I've updated my answer please see that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML unicode `&#9776;` for hamburger icon

You can find more at here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

```css
.navbar-toggle
{
font-size:25px; 
background:none; 
border:none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">&#9776;                 
</button>
```

You can also animate the icon see: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js

Comment: Thanks, it truly helped me, that was exactly what I was needing :)